# How to change background color for a dropdown option in Google Sheet via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with dropdown option.

Under Data Validation rules, it is possible to change one of the option background.

My question is that is it possible to change the option background via Google Sheet Apps Script Workspace services?

[Data Validation rules in Google Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld4sN.png)

Note that I am trying to change the option background color, not the cell background.

I have checked the return value for Data Validation Criteria but it seems that the background color information was not returned.

[Retrieving Data Validation Criteria value does not contain the background color information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZon6.png)

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var rule = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet5").getRange(2,2).getDataValidation();

  var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
  var args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
  Logger.log('The data validation rule is %s %s', criteria, args);
}
```

I could not find how to obtain or edit this background color via script to have the same result as the screenshot above.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please take this opportunity to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like there isn't any preset functions or methods as of now to be able to change the item color for data validation. I'd suggest submitting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) instead.

Comment: Same here. Have you solved the problem?